# Delphi proper use of TMultiView

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

As you know there is a new component called TMultiView that can be user as navigation drawer if you set the mode to `Drawer`. Let's say that I have a drawer with 5 buttons inside and each of them, when clicked, shows in the main form a particular layout.

I was thinking that I could add to my form a lot of `TLayout` and set their visibility to false. Then, when I click in a button of the Drawer, I set the respective visibility to true/false.

I am not sure if this is a good way to structure the app. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you see `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\[your version]\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\MultiView` sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to place a TabControl on the form. As you have 5 buttons and want 5 different "layouts" you would add 5 tabs to the TabControl. On each tab place a TLayout.

At design time it is straight forward to design each of the layouts.

At run time switch to the appropriate layout.